# Generating Sentences Using Python

Tags: python

I need to generate sentences using python. I have the words I need intact but can't figure out how to make it so only correct sentences come out after I run it.

Here's my code

```
import random

def S():
    print DP(), VP()

def DP():
    detPhrase = D() + ' ' + N()
    return detPhrase

def VP():
    randInt = random.randint(0,1)
    if randInt == 0:
        return V() 
    else:
        return V() + ' ' + DP()

def N():
    nouns = ['cat', 'dog', 'Bella']
    randInt = random.randint(0,len(nouns)-1)
    return nouns[randInt]

def D():
    articles = ['the', 'to']
    randInt = random.randint(0,len(articles)-1)
    return articles[randInt]

def V():
    verbs = ['ran','kissed','gave']
    randInt = random.randint(0,len(verbs)-1)
    return verbs[randInt]

for num in range(30):
    S()
```

Comment: Please indent your code properly, and choose more descriptive names.

Comment: What is your desired output and what output are you seeing? You need to be a lot more specific in your question.

Comment: @WaleedKhan: These names - S, DP, VP, N, D, V - are used frequently by linguists. They denote Sentence, Determinant-Phrase, Verb-Phrase, Noun, Determinant, Verb, respectively.

Comment: Right now the program generates grammatical sentences and ungrammatical sentences like 
The cat ran.
b. The cat kissed the tree. a. *The Bella ran.
b. *The cat kissed.
c. *The cat ran the tree. Now I just need it to only generate the correct sentences

Comment: This is probably out of the scale of your project, but have you looked at nltk?

Comment: I apologize if the code is basic or isn't specific. I'm new to coding and this problem was thrown kind of out of the blue from the instructor.

Comment: @user2059838: You tagged "The Bella ran" with an asterisk, marking it as ungrammatical. What if "The Bella" was a warship under attack from an enemy and fled from the battle? Then the sentence "The Bella ran" would obviously a valid and grammatically correct sentence.

Comment: You are experiencing the problem with natural languages: while "The Bella ran" is *syntactically* correct, it may or may not be *semantically* correct, as pillmuncher points out. You need contextual information far beyond the scope of a simple grammar to resolve such issues. Some problems you can fix; for example, you don't distinguish between transitive and intransitive verbs, which is how you get "The cat kissed" and "The cat ran the tree".

Comment: @user2059838: Also, there are many things your program lacks: agreement of number/gender/case, distinction between transitive and intranistive verbs, noun phrases without determinants, and different forms of sentences. If you'd be programming in Prolog it'd be a snap, but in Python I know of no easy way of implementing a proper sentence generator - short of reimplementing Prolog in Python.

Answer (score 2):

Read up about Chomsky hierarchy: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_hierarchy#Formal_grammars

Answer (score 1):

About 6 months ago I remembered the old [racter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Racter) program, and cobbled together a Python variation. It's probably closer to MadLib's than actual sentence generation. I packaged it as an online utility at Utility Mill: http://utilitymill.com/utility/Graduation_speech

Answer (score 1):

You can make a big improvement by identifying the parts of speech correctly: **"to" is a preposition, not an article**.

```
articles = ['the', 'a']
```

It's not Shakespeare, but at least we're in the ballpark:

```
a dog kissed the dog
a dog kissed the dog
the cat kissed
a cat kissed
a cat gave the dog
a dog kissed the cat
the dog gave
a dog kissed the dog
```

Answer (score 0):

Over the christmas holidays I wrote [hornet](https://github.com/pillmuncher/hornet), which is a Prolog-like embedded DSL in Python 3.3. It is not very good yet -being only a proof of concept-, and comes with no documentation to speak of, but with a file *[parsing.py](https://github.com/pillmuncher/hornet/blob/master/parsing.py)* that contains DCG-rules for simple german sentences. You could try it out and take a look at the code. Maybe it is of some help to you.